# Cortex M4 SVC code appears to always pass in 255 for the SVC number

Tags: assembly, arm, interrupt, inline-assembly, cortex-m

I've tried following the documentation to make an SVC instruction work. From the Arm documentation [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka004005/latest) my SVC_Handler function is as they specify:

```
void SVC_Handler(void)
{
  __asm(
    ".global SVC_Handler_Main\n"
    "TST lr, #4\n"
    "ITE EQ\n"
    "MRSEQ r0, MSP\n"
    "MRSNE r0, PSP\n"
    "B SVC_Handler_Main\n"
  ) ;
}
```

My SVC_Handler_Main's first few lines is again just like they specify:

```
void SVC_Handler_Main( unsigned int *svc_args )
{
  unsigned int svc_number;

  /*
  * Stack contains:
  * r0, r1, r2, r3, r12, r14, the return address and xPSR
  * First argument (r0) is svc_args[0]
  */
  svc_number = ( ( char * )svc_args[ 6 ] )[ -2 ] ;
  switch( svc_number )
  {...
```

When I run the following code:

```
__asm("SVC #17"); //17 is an example number
```

No matter what, the variable `svc_number` is always 255. The SVC actually triggers just fine and I can do whatever I want inside of it...as long as the svc_number of 255 is used. Any other number just gets set to 255. Did I miss something?

This is an STM32F401RE chip on a Nucleo board.

Comment: `void SVC_Handler(void)` without `__attribute__((naked))` or `__attribute__((interrupt))` is super broken; in a debug build the compiler will emit code to make a stack frame at the top of the function, before the `asm("...")` statement runs, changing the stack pointer and potentially modifying registers.  At least GCC and clang will; I don't know what compiler ARM's talking about where that's not broken.

Comment: Also, `.global SVC_Handler_Main` is weird and redundant; the compiler will already emit that because `SVC_Handler_Main` isn't `static`.  If they meant `.extern SVC_Handler_Main`, that would be a no-op for GAS; all undeclared symbols are assumed external.

Comment: does the number you get match what you had in r0 when you called it?  In order to extract the svc number from the instruction you need to take the instruction apart, which is not on the stack.  the registers are on the stack.   does anyone actually use the number passed in the immediate part of the instruciton?  I assume not because once thumb happend extracting the number became more painful

Comment: try changing r0 before the call and see if the results change.  I see nothing in this code that attempts to get the number from the instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have searched far and wide and have figured out the issue. I'm not entirely sure why, but the code provided by ARM didn't work as written, despite using the STM32CubeIDE. I had to re-write the SVC_Handler function so that both volatile and naked attributes were used. It looks like this now and works just fine:

```
__attribute__ ((naked)) void SVC_Handler(void) {
  __asm volatile(".global SVC_Handler_Main");
  __asm volatile("TST LR, 4"); // check LR to know which stack is used
  __asm volatile("ITE EQ"); // 2 next instructions are conditional
  __asm volatile("MRSEQ R0, MSP"); // save MSP if bit 2 is 0
  __asm volatile("MRSNE R0, PSP"); // save PSP if bit 2 is 1
  __asm volatile("B SVC_Handler_Main"); // pass R0 as the argument
}
```

Comment: The `__asm("...\n...\n...")` statement in the original was implicitly `volatile` because it's a "Basic" asm statement (thus [not generally safe in non-`naked` functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended) since you can't tell the compiler about modified registers).  Just adding `__attribute__ ((naked)) ` would be sufficient.  One large `asm` statement (or `asm volatile` if you want to be explicit) is equivalent to what you're doing here, since it's a `naked` function so compiler-generated asm can't possibly get put between any of your `asm` statements, because there is none.

Comment: The code you posted is wrong.  It splits `__asm` statements into multiple parts assuming that registers are preserved.  This is an incorrect assumption.  Do not program this way.

Comment: @fuz: That was my first reaction, but then I noticed it was inside a `naked` function which makes this 100% fine.  It doesn't matter where you have one or multiple Basic `asm` statements inside a `naked` function; it's not officially supported to have anything else.  So there are no compiler-generated instructions and it can't inline.  Style-wise I find it ugly and cluttered, and you can't use a similar style anywhere else, but OTOH you shouldn't use Basic asm at all anywhere else, except global scope (where you should use one single `asm` statement.)